# Automount Virtualbox shared folders in fstab ArchLinux

Tags: virtualbox, archlinux, shared-directory

My host machine is Windows7 and I'm running Apache in a Archlinux guest, have all virtualbox additions instaled.
I dont know, how can make automount virtualbox shared folder in fstab. 
I try add this row in fstab:

```
/media/sf_www /home/petr/public_html vboxsf defaults 0 0
```

Whats wrong?
**Failed to mount /home/petr/public_html**

Folder public_html exist in /home/petr and has 775 mask.

Thx

Comment: Here's the actual issue. `/media/sf_www` is probably marked as an Auto Mount shared folder from VirtualBox. This folder isn't mounted until the guest OS is fully up and running. This means `/meda/sf_www` was not available when mount started mounting `/etc/fstab` entries. Modify the Auto Mount in VirtualBox to mount it in `/home/petr/public_html` instead of `/media/sf_www`.

Comment: Understand, my shared folder has name www so row in fstab will be
**/media/www /home/petr/public_html vboxsf defaults 0 0**
after change have same errors.

Comment: Allow me rephrase what I said. VirtualBox additions do this automatically for you. You don't need to put it in `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about auto-mounting the virtualbox way, and can accept not using fstab, try [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986166/how-does-one-configure-shared-folders-to-automount-for-arch-manjaro-linux-vm-in) that worked for me, by enabling the virtualbox service. It seems that Arch doesn't automatically enable this service.