# How does one configure shared folders to automount for arch/manjaro linux VM in virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, shared-directory, automount, manjaro

I have a manjaro/arch virtual machine running in virtualbox with a windows 10 host.  I have configured the shared folder I want to share in virtualbox as `c:\tfs` with the name `tfs` but it doesn't show up in the linux vm anywhere.  I am able to mount it manually, but it won't auto-mount.  I created the `/media` and `/media/tfs` folder in the VM, since it did not exist, and now the following command successfully manually mounts my folder `sudo mount -t vboxsf tfs /media/tfs`.  How do I get the automount to work as intended without resorting to editing `/etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that a few more steps are needed to configure the automount for shared folders of virtualbox.  This tiny [forum post](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/4s380h/vbox_guest_automounting_shared_folders_does_not/) was the key.  You need to enable and start the virtualbox service `vboxservice.service` installed with the guest utils.

1. First ensure you have a folder `/media`, this is where it will try to mount your shared folders
2. Ensure that the guest utils are installed with `sudo pacman -Q virtualbox-guest-utils`
3. Enable service with `sudo systemctl enable vboxservice.service`
4. Start service with `sudo systemctl start vboxservice.service`
5. Reboot, I tried just logging out but reboot was necessary for me to start the service
6. Verify that your folder is now automounted in `/media` with `sf_` prefix, mine is `/media/sf_tfs`

   p.s. I also ran this command based on another post to add my username to the vboxsf group, although I'm not sure whether this one was necessary or not. `sudo usermod -aG vboxsf brandon`

Comment: I tested this on my computer and it worked beautifully. I did need to do the sudo usermod -aG vboxsf ... command as well

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I needed to add my user to the vboxsf group, too. One extra tidbit: If you let virtualbox create the `/media` folder, it'll create that as owned by root:root. I ran `sudo chown root:vboxsf /media` to be able to use it from my non-root account.